# terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector c++

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I'm trying to use a recursive function to apply a connectivity graph algorithm on a directed graph. The recursive function is in the Graph class and is called `StrongDFS()`. When the program reaches the for loop it crashes and gives me the /*error message:

```
"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type      std::out_of_range: vector
check1check1Run Command: line 1: 72739 Abort trap: 6           ./"$2" "${@:3}""
```

I can't figure out why there would be an issue with the vector at that point in the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
     #include <stack>
    using namespace std;


    class Vertex {
      public:
        int currentDist; // needs to be updated 
        int id; // use id as index 
        int pred;
        int num; 
        int in_stack; 
        vector<int> neighbors; // These need to be parallel 


       void setId (const int& x){
          id = x; 
           setNum(0);
           setPred(0);
        }
        void onStack(int os){
            in_stack = os; 
    }
        void addToniegh (const int& n){
          neighbors.push_back(n);
        }

        void setNum(int sn){
        num = sn; 
    }
        void setPred(int p){
        pred = p; 
        }

        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Vertex ver);
    };

    class Graph {   // this class is going to contain the dequeue and print out the graph 
      public:
      vector<Vertex*> verticies; // a list of all verticies 
      int w;// a counter 
      int c2; 
      int count; 
      int temp; 
      stack<int> theStack;   // the numbers wait, if less than the head add to front 
       Vertex vertex; 
      void addVert (Vertex* v){
        verticies.push_back(v);
      }

        int StrongDFS(int sd){
            count++; 
            verticies[sd-1]->setPred(count); 
            verticies[sd-1]->setNum(count); 
            theStack.push(verticies[sd-1]->id);
             cout << "Stack: " << theStack.top() << endl;   
            verticies[sd - 1]->onStack(1);
            cout << verticies[sd-1]->num << "  " << verticies[sd-1]->pred << " " << verticies[sd-1]->neighbors.size() << endl;  
            cout << "hello"<< endl; 
            for (int i = 0; i < verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.size(); i++){
                   cout << "check1";
                if (verticies[sd - 1]->num == 0){
                    cout << "CHECK";
                    StrongDFS(verticies[sd-1]->neighbors.at(i));
                    if (verticies[sd - 1]->pred > verticies[verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.at(i) - 1]->pred)
                        verticies[sd - 1]->setPred(verticies[verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.at(i) - 1]->pred);
                    }   
                else if (verticies[verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.at(i)]->num < verticies[sd - 1]->num && verticies[verticies[sd]->neighbors.at(i)]->in_stack == 1){
                    if (verticies[sd - 1]->pred > verticies[verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.at(i) - 1]->num)
                        verticies[sd - 1]->setPred(verticies[verticies[sd - 1]->neighbors.at(i) - 1]->num);
                }}
            if (verticies[sd-1]->pred == verticies[sd - 1]->num){
                w = theStack.top();
                verticies[w - 1]->onStack(0);
                theStack.pop();     
                while (w != sd){
                     cout << "output " << char(w + 'a' - 1) << endl;  
                    w = theStack.top(); 
                    verticies[w - 1]->onStack(0);
                    theStack.pop();
                }
                cout << "output " << char(w + 'a' - 1) << endl;  
            }
            return w; 

            }
            //return NULL; 
      };
    ostream& operator << (ostream& out, Vertex ver) {
      out << char(ver.id+'a'-1) <<  " (" ;
      for (int i = 0; i < ver.neighbors.size(); i++){ 
        if (i != ver.neighbors.size()- 1)
          cout << char(ver.neighbors.at(i)+'a'-1)  << ", ";
        else 
          cout << char(ver.neighbors.at(i)+'a'-1); 
      }
      cout << ")  "<< "current Distance: " << ver.currentDist << endl; 

      return out; 
    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
         Vertex v1; //  A
          Vertex v2; // B 
          Vertex v3; // C
          Vertex v4; // D
          Vertex v5; // E
          Vertex v6; // F
          Vertex v7; // G
          Vertex v8; // H 
          Graph g1;

          // - - - - - - - - - - - - A
          v1.setId(1);
          v1.addToniegh(3); // c
          v1.addToniegh(4); // d

          // - - - - - - - -- - - - - B
          v2.setId(2);
          v2.addToniegh(6); // f 
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - - C
          v3.setId(3);
          v3.addToniegh(1); // a
          v3.addToniegh(5);  // e
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - - D
          v4.setId(4);
          v4.addToniegh(2); // b
          v4.addToniegh(5); // e
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - -  E 
          v5.setId(5);
          v5.addToniegh(6); // f
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - F
          v6.setId(6);
          v6.addToniegh(7);  // g
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - G
          v7.setId(7);
          // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - H
          v8.setId(8);
          v8.addToniegh(6); // f

          //----Adding them to vector in Graph ---
          g1.addVert(&v1);
          g1.addVert(&v2);
          g1.addVert(&v3);
          g1.addVert(&v4);
          g1.addVert(&v5);
          g1.addVert(&v6);
          g1.addVert(&v7);
          g1.addVert(&v8);
          g1.StrongDFS(1);
          //cout << endl;    
          //cout << g1; // I print here 
          //g1.proc();  // I start the graph here
          //cout << g1; // I print here 
    }
```

Comment: Narrow it down please. You're expected to do the debugging yourself then come to us with questions about programming languages if you're missing any facts. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One issue right away that I see is that you did not initialize your member variables for `Vertex`.

You construct a `Vertex` object, leaving the members in an uninitialized state.  The issue then appears on lines like this:

`verticies[sd - 1]->num`

When I use Visual Studio, I am getting wild numbers for `num`, all due to the member variable being uninitialized.  On the output, I'm getting this:

```
Stack: 1
-858993459  -858993459 2
```

You should write a default constructor that initializes your member variables:

```
class Vertex {
public:
    int currentDist; // needs to be updated 
    int id; // use id as index 
    int pred;
    int num;
    int in_stack;
    vector<int> neighbors; // These need to be parallel 
    Vertex() : currentDist(0), id(0), pred(0), num(0), in_stack(0) {}
//...
};
```

You also do the same thing with your `Graph` object.  You create a Graph with members that are uninitialized.  The `Graph` should have a default constructor:

```
Graph() : count(0), temp(0), c2(0), w(0) {}
```

Without this, the `count` is uninitialized, and your `StrongDFS` function starts out all messed up here:

```
    count++;
```

Since `count` is uninitialized, you don't know what `count` will be.

Having uninitialized members is not good practice, especially if you're going to use those members later on.

Now whether these changes ultimately fix your problem, I don't know.  What I do know is that you must make these changes due to the variables obviously being used before they have initial values.